# Does the List<T> class declare a single event member called Changed?

Tags: c#

An example of event in C# 4.0 Spec [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=s-IH_x6ytuQC&pg=PT92&lpg=PT92&dq=List%3CT%3E%20class%20declared%20a%20single%20event%20member%20called%20Changed,&source=bl&ots=lr867XeUdV&sig=zfUKKKGxFH9ZD4M8VJxCwH9ndgE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o8OtT-DXG42I6AGxhMmeCQ&ved=0CF4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) says that

`"The List<T> class declares a single event member called Changed, which indicates that a new item has been added to the list. The Changed event is raised by the OnChanged virtual method, which first checks whether the event is null (meaning that no handlers are present). The notion of raising an event is precisely equivalent to invoking the delegate represented by the event—thus, there are no special language constructs for raising events."`

I can't find the event `Changed` by Reflector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true for `List<T>` class defined in the book. It has nothing to do with .Net Framework `class System.Collection.Generic.List<T>`.

And yes, if you would copy the class from the book it will have Changed event.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the documentation to indicate any events exist on a `List<T>`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from List and add your own handler, something like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test {
    class Program {

        class MyList<T> : List<T> 
        {
            public event EventHandler OnAdd;

            public void Add(T item) 
            {
                if (null != OnAdd)
                    OnAdd(this, null);

                base.Add(item);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            MyList<int> l = new MyList<int>();
            l.OnAdd += new EventHandler(l_OnAdd);
            l.Add(1);
        }

        static void l_OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element added...");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking for such a list, try [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) (which has ListChanged) or [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)